# Ubuntu 14.0.4 LTS Crashes and freezes many times just after installation

Tags: 14.04, windows, hard-drive, windows-8, hardware

Hello everyone and thanks for opening this thread; 
My computer works fine when I boot windows 8.1, but booting Ubuntu, I will surely face a system crash ( or freez), some times it takes one or two days but it's inescapable. The system is so unreliable and unstable. Even in the ordinary jobs like web browsing using google chrome it lags. Ubuntu is updated and upgraded. HDD rustles a lot when I'm using Ubuntu, It's too much noisy there while it works totally fine with windows. Got a test with HDTUNE and the HDD is okay. There must be something wrong here, I know many servers use Ubuntu so it should not be like that...I will appreciate any answer from you.

System specification: CPU: Intel Core i5 Broadwell- 5200u Memory:6GB Graphics: Nvidia Geforce GT840M HDD: ST1000LM024 (1TB Seagate)

Comment: Check this if Ubuntu freezes http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes may be this could solve. Also there might be issue with the GPU or PSU also check that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install a proprietary driver for you video adapter.
Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-prime
```

and reboot.